# What does the following java statement mean

Tags: java, syntax

I'm reviewing java and stumbled upon something like the following block of code

```
public Foo example()
Foo bar = new Foo(...);
...
return new Foo[]{bar};
```

what does Foo[]{bar} mean in this context? Is it returning an array of Foo objects populated by bar? Seems to be something really trivial but I'm not sure what how to search for it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's creating an array with a single element, initially set to the value of `bar`. You can use this syntax for more elements though, e.g.

```
new int[] { 1, 2, 3 }
```

This is an *ArrayCreationExpression*, as specified in [section 15.10 of the Java Language Specification](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#46168), using an *ArrayInitializer* as specified in [section 10.6](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/arrays.html#10.6).

Comment: Ah that makes sense. Thanks for the links. Surprising to find them not redirect to oracle's pages.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. It's an array of one element. That element being `bar`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's right. This constructs a single-element array of `Foo` that consists only of the element `bar`.

Answer (score 1):

The equivalent code would be

```
Foo[] foos = new Foo[1];
foos[0] = bar;
return foos;
```

Answer (score 1):

- Create an instance of the class Foo on line 2 when you say new Foo(...)
- In the next line you are returning an array.
- The "type" of the array is "Foo"
- A member in the array that you are returning is "bar"

Answer (score 0):

It is returning an array with the contents being bar.